# Is it possible to construct a smooth "flat-top bump function"?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is it possible to find a smooth function $p$ such that
>
> $$p(x)=0 \text{ if } x\le -1$$
> $$p(x)=0 \text{ if } x> 0$$
> $$0\le p(x) \le 1 \text{ if } -1<x<1$$
> $$p(x) = 1 \text{ if } -\frac{1}{2}\le x \le \frac{1}{2}$$
> *Hint*: The following function has continuous derivatives of all orders
> $$f(x) = 0 \text{ if } x\le 0$$
> $$f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \text{ if } x>0$$

My thought: Considering the left-half of the function $p$, I tried something like $e^{-\frac{1}{\tan^2(x\pi)}}$. The shape looks good but I am not sure about the smoothness at $-1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$. For $x=-1$, since $\tan$ is infinitely differentiable so we have smoothness there. But for $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, I am not sure about the smoothness after "gluing" with $y=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a smoothed bump function with $f(x) = 0$ for $|x| \geq 1,$ then for $-1 < x < 1$ take
$$  f(x) = e^{\frac{1}{x^2 -1}}. $$
Next we can make a $C^\infty$ mock Heaviside function with 
$$  h(x) = \int_{- \infty}^x f(t) dt $$
Note that $h$ is constant for $x \leq -1,$ where it is zero, and $x \geq 1,$ where $h$ is a fixed definite integral, call it $H.$

We get a flat-top plateau function with, for some $X > 1,$
$$  F(x) = \frac{1}{H^2} h(x +  X) h(    -X - x).  $$